# AWS S3 private public file sharing

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on rails app using fog and aws-ruby -sdk v2.
Can someone  please direct me to resources attach public and private files in S3 bucket at runtime of the web app.
Have used UserPolicy and Bucket Policy but to no success.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you are trying to archive?

Comment: When i upload files to S3 through my application it should not be made visible to public.
Currently when I am uploading the file it can be viewed by anyone.